# ckeditor with ckfinder integrating with codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckfinder

I successfully configured ckeditor with ckfinder (it works outside CI) but when i click the browse button i get the link:

```
 http://localhost/timeline/index.php/ckfinder.html?type=Images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

The correct link should have ckfinder in place of index.php which is trying to access a controller and gives 404 error from CI.

I'm doing something wrong in config file of ckfinder?
Please note that i'm not using any htaccess or routing feature of CI.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ckeditor config.js the following lines solved the problem.

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
```